# Can a scalar multiple for a linearly dependant vector be undefined?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\
2a & 2b & 2c \\
e & f & g\end{bmatrix}$

where $R_{3}$ is linearly independent of $R_{1}$, 
Clearly, $(-2 , 1, 0)$ will be set of scalars such that
$k_{1} * R_{1} + k_{2} * R_{2} + k_{3} * R_{3} = 0$. Using this equation, can we say that $R_{3}$ can be expressed as linear combination of $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$?

I feel it does not makes sense because it will require $R_{1}, R_{2}$ to have undefined coefficients (-2/0 & 1/0), but I find a related question in an exam whose answer key claims that statement "Each row of A can be represented as linear combination of other rows" is true.

Comment: "Each row of A can be represented as linear combination of other rows" does not follow from "The rows of A are linearly dependent."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explicitly said that $R_3$ is linearly independent with $R_1$. It's clear that $R_2=2R_1$, so since $R_2$ is a scalar multiple of $R_1$, $R_3$ is also linearly independent with $\{R_1, R_2\}$, since any linear combination of those two vectors is the same as a scalar multiple of $R_1$. Thus, no, $R_3$ can not be written as a linear combination of $R_1$ and $R_2$.

Even though the set of $R_1, R_2, R_3$ as whole is linearly dependent, this does not mean each row can be written as a linear combination of the other rows. Your example is a clear demonstration of this since in your linear dependence equation, $k_3=0$, so you can not divide out $k_3$ and subtract in order to get a linear combination of $R_1$ and $R_2$ equal to $R_3$ because dividing by $0$ is undefined.

Comment: how do we reconcile this with, $R_{3} = -R_{1} * (k_{1} / k_{3}) - R_{2}*(k_{2} / k_{])$

Comment: @Pranav That formula only works when $k_3 \neq 0$. In that formula, you have to divide by $k_3$, so if $k_3=0$, this means you divide by $0$, so it doesn't work when $k_3=0$.